# SHA1 hexadecimal encoding in scala

Tags: python, scala, hash

I need to convert string to SHA1 hexadecimal hash below is the code I am using:

```
val md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")
val ha = new sun.misc.HexDumpEncoder().encode(md.digest("Foo".getBytes))
print(ha)
```

but i donot get hexadecimal value,
I can achive this in python using below piece of code:

```
int(hashlib.sha1("Foo".encode(encoding='UTF-8', errors='strict')).hexdigest(), 16)
```

what is the relevent `hexdigest()` of python in scala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically any java way to convert byte array to string will do the job.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java) is a thread discussing different options to convert byte array to hex string.

You can try this way.

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
val md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")
val ha = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(md.digest("Foo".getBytes))
print(ha)
```

In order to create integer from the string you will have to use BigInteger, because Int and Long will overflow.

```
val i = new BigInteger(ha, 16)
// this will overflow for this input
val i2 = Integer.parseInt(ha, 16)
import java.lang.{ Long => JLong }
val l = JLong.parseLong(ha, 16)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this works but i really have hard time converting string to int of base 16 in scala!